# Data explosion when run bsc node

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc

I have a machine : 16 core, 32G RAM, 2T SSD.

When I build bsc node with geth config "--cache 16000 --syncmode full --gcmode full ",
I see that the capacity of the directory containing node **increases 1.8G/h**. That means I lose approx **43G per day** or **320G per week**.

Now (2/8/2021) the capacity of the directory containing node is 724.6G. With this data explosion  i think i just can maintain my node for a month.

**I wonder if there is any solution for me to reduce the increasing data size and maintain my node for a longer time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when doing the initial sync, you should do a "fast" or "snap" sync, not a "full" sync. Fast and snap sync will take about 400Gb initially.

When the initial sync is completed, the node will automatically switch to "full" sync. Following that, the node will increase about 40Gb / day as you observed. **Edit: You can reduce the increase rate by increasing the TrieTimeout value, as described [here](https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/releases/tag/v1.1.1).**

When you need to reduce the node size again, you can either do a completely new sync or, if you used snap sync, [offline prune](https://gist.github.com/yorickdowne/3323759b4cbf2022e191ab058a4276b2) your node.

Comment: Did you try running a bsc node? and your node also increased about 40Gb / day right?

Comment: Yes I run a bsc node. I did not calculate precisely, but 40Gb/day would really be the max when all the blocks are always full. Like today, the blocks are half-full so it would be closer to 20Gb/day. It really has increased a lot in the past few weeks (blocks are often full)...